# C++ Selection Sort with class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor, selection-sort

I have a bunch of codelines and I cannot do what I want.

I have a specific array numbers and I need to re-order them and return it as array for further use (like for loop inside of main(){}) Also I must do this with Selection Sort algorithm and inside of Class const.

Array must return like this [-9.34, -9.34, 1.12, 3.32, 3.34, 3.45, 9.44, 10.75, 55.34] and i must able to use it inside of for loop.

[Selection Sort - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class selection_sort {
    int say;
    double arrs[];
public: selection_sort(double arr[], int say) {
    int min_a;
    double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < say - 1; i++) {
        min_a = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < say; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_a])
                min_a = j;
        }

        if (min_a != i) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min_a];
            arr[min_a] = temp;
            arrs[i] = arr[i];

        }
    }
    //return arrs;
}
        double yaz() {
            //for (int i = 0; i < say; i++){
            //  cout << arrs[i] << endl;
            //}
            return arrs;
        }
};
void main() {
    double s_dizi[] = { 3.45, -9.34, 1.12, 55.34, -9.34, 3.34, 9.44, 3.32, 10.75 };
    selection_sort ob(s_dizi, 10), *p;
    p = &ob;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        // like do this...
        cout<<p->yaz()[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I'm so sorry for my english. I will explain any further question.

Comment: You should explain the problem you're having. Just saying what your code must do is not very descriptive of what _it actually does_.

Comment: Hi @aslg , well in the wikipedia link, you can see what i want. I just need to re-order the array based on Selection Sort algoralgorithmıI have to do this Within a Class{ }. Not just a  simple function(){ }